# rewriting url for replicated sites using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having a problem rewriting the URL of a replicated site.

a replicated site has this format: `https://domainname/sitename`

so if you go into a subdirecotry in the system, url should look like this:

`https://domainname/sitename/sub1`

What I've tried so far is doing this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)/index(.+)$       
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?_route_=$2 [PT,L]
```

which solves this format: `https://domainname/sitename/sub1`.
But after putting up that rule it no longer accepts this `https://domainname/sitename`

Answer (score 0):

The regex in your RewriteRule expects a string followed by a slash followed by a string, which won't match `sitename`. You can change the regex to check for characters until the first slash and then an optional string (including slashes) after that:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+(/(.+))*$ index.php?_route_=$2 [PT,L]
```

See the explanation [on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IE2GXi/1)

The values for `$_GET['_route_']` will be:

- https://domainname/sitename => (empty string)
- https://domainname/sitename/sub1 => `sub1`
- https://domainname/sitename/sub1/sub2 => `sub1/sub2`

if you also want to pass the sitename, you need to put it in a capturing group, which will increase the group index:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/(.+))*$ index.php?_site_=$1&_route_=$3 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also recommended that you just replace that entire ruleset with

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

And then add the smarts to index.php to parse PATH_INFO

This we'll be more efficient and customizable.